# Getting timezone from IP address in node js

Tags: node.js, timezone, ip, utc, geoip

What is the simplest and best way to get the timezone from an ip in node.js? Ideally without calling a webservice (any free webservice solutions are also welcome).

Uptil now I have managed to find the 2 letter *ISO-3166-1 country code*, *latitude/longitude*, *ISO-3166-2 subcountry code*, *FIPS 10-4 subcountry code* and the *city name* from the npm module *geoip-lite*.

How would I go about translating this data to a timezone or a utc offset? Or maybe an easier way is to directly map the ip to the timezone.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[satelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/satelize) can do that.

```
var satelize = require('satelize');
satelize.satelize({ip:'46.19.37.108'}, function(err, payload) {
});
```

Output includes timezone

```
{
    "ip": "46.19.37.108",
    "continent_code": "EU",
    "continent": {
      "de": "Europa",
      "en": "Europe"
    },
    "country_code": "NL",
    "country": {
      "de": "Niederlande",
      "en": "Netherlands"
    },
    "latitude": 52.5,
    "longitude": 5.75,
    "timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam"
}
```